# COUNT(*) not working with group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why the following query returns NO RESULT in MySQL 5.6 on empty database ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM a_sec_banns 
WHERE ip = 'not-exist-ip' 
GROUP BY ip 
HAVING max(date_created) <= '10-10-2014' or count(*) > 3;
```

The structure of table is something like  this:

```
CREATE TABLE `a_sec_banns` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DATE_CREATED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would expect the query COUNT(*) will return a number > 0, 0 if nothing, Exception if query is wrong. But never NULL - what is the NULL/NO result purpose on COUNT ???

Comment: doesn't make sense to filter on only one ip and group by ip.

Comment: Empty table, no results, seems to me how things should work? There are 0 records which fall into your `HAVING` clause (`max(date_created) <= '10-10-2014' or count(*) > 3`)

Comment: Provide some input data..

Comment: @Wrikken yes, there are no data which fall into having clause. Count of rows on no data should return 0. From business point of view I want to ask how many items are in empty set. The answer should be 0 not empty.

Comment: I have found that the following query returns 0 correctly, but why do hell we need to do it in such way: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A_SEC_BANNS dbbann0_ 
WHERE dbbann0_.IP = (
select
        dbbann0_.IP as col_0_0_ 
    from
        A_SEC_BANNS dbbann0_ 
    where
        dbbann0_.IP='10.10.10.10'
    group by
        dbbann0_.IP 
    having
        max(dbbann0_.DATE_CREATED) <= '10-10-2014'
        OR count(*)>3);

Comment: @SonalPM there are NO data, database is empty

Comment: @kulatamicuda I'm saying that if you instruct MySQL to NOT return rows with a count of < 3 or max date < a date, and that's all the rows it has... it will return NO rows, because that's what you asked from it. Gordon Linoff below elaborates on exactly why this happens.

Comment: @kulatamicuda regarding your second query (in the comments): it is a matter of the scope of count(), of what gets counted. When using aggregated datasets, (GROUP BY..), count counts within the aggregates - in your case there are no aggregates, so there are no count results. When using count() on a simple select..where.., it counts the results of the whole query, so even an empty resultset get counted as 0

Comment: @cypherable Now I understand, thanks to all for comments and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM a_sec_banns 
WHERE ip = 'not-exist-ip' 
GROUP BY ip 
HAVING max(date_created) <= '10-10-2014' or count(*) > 3;
```

If you ran just the first part on an empty database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM a_sec_banns 
WHERE ip = 'not-exist-ip' 
GROUP BY ip ;
```

You would get one row with the value of `0`.

However, the `having` clause filters out this one row.  `max(date_created)` would be `NULL` and the `count(*)` would be 0, so both conditions would fail.

By the way, you should use ISO standard date formats.  So, the `having` clause should read:

```
HAVING max(date_created) <= '2014-10-10' or count(*) > 3;
```

This will help when the table actually does have data.

EDITED:
it is a matter of the scope of count(), of what gets counted. When using aggregated datasets, (GROUP BY..), count counts within the aggregates - in your case there are no aggregates, so there are no count results. When using count() on a simple select..where.., it counts the results of the whole query, so even an empty resultset get counted as 0

Comment: added comment from cypherabe, closed it and added +1

Answer (score 0):

Although the last part of your query does not really make sense, this will fix your problem:

1. When create this table, have the ip default as `not-exist-ip` like this:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE a_sec_banns (
     ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     DATE_CREATED datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     IP varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL 'not-exist-ip',
     PRIMARY KEY (ID)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   ```
2. In your query, use the database datetime for comparison like `2014-10-10 00:00:00` as in:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM a_sec_banns 
   WHERE ip = 'not-exist-ip' 
   GROUP BY ip 
   HAVING max(date_created) <= '2014-10-10 00:00:00' or count(*) > 3;
   ```

Comment: This does not solve problem. The query returns not 0, but no result.

Comment: I tested it with made up data and it worked. Show me your sample data

Comment: Your sample data should have 'not-exist-ip' to return results