# Unable to count the number of rows returned from query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query

**MYSQL:**

```
SELECT COUNT(op.quantity) AS quantity_sold, op.model AS model_number,
op.name AS product_name, ptc.category_id, cd.name 
FROM ((`order_product` op INNER JOIN `product` p ON op.product_id = p.product_id) 
INNER JOIN (`product_to_category` ptc 
INNER JOIN `category_description` cd ON ptc.category_id = cd.category_id) ON op.product_id = ptc.product_id)
INNER JOIN `order` o on o.order_id = op.order_id  GROUP BY op.model ORDER BY quantity_sold DESC;
```

I tried this code to count the no. of rows for the above result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM ((`order_product` op INNER JOIN `product` p ON op.product_id = p.product_id) 
INNER JOIN (`product_to_category` ptc 
INNER JOIN `category_description` cd ON ptc.category_id = cd.category_id) ON op.product_id = ptc.product_id)
INNER JOIN `order` o on o.order_id = op.order_id  GROUP BY op.model;
```

But I am unable to get the count single value.

I need the count of rows returned from the first query as a single value for the purpose of pagination.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Are you getting a wrong result? An error?

Comment: please provide your table schema and a clear explanation of what you need.

Comment: Very similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671483/count-not-working-with-group-by

Comment: unable to add images .. due to 10 reputation point requried

Comment: I am getting result like 10,9,9,9,9,9 ...

Comment: NOT a single row .. I need the result for this whole query.

Comment: Maybe you need a `count(distinct op.quantity)`?

Comment: @StephanBauer : It Also not worked .. :(

Comment: @StephanBauer : I requried the row count for the pagination purpose. Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the row count that your query returns, wrapping it in an outer query should give you what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS row_count FROM (

  SELECT 
      COUNT(op.quantity) AS quantity_sold, 
      op.model AS model_number,
      op.name AS product_name, 
      ptc.category_id, 
      cd.name 
  FROM order_product op 
  INNER JOIN product p ON op.product_id = p.product_id
  INNER JOIN product_to_category ptc ON op.product_id = ptc.product_id
  INNER JOIN category_description cd ON ptc.category_id = cd.category_id
  INNER JOIN `order` o on o.order_id = op.order_id  
  GROUP BY op.model
  ORDER BY quantity_sold DESC
) A;
```

Comment: @VIM Try this query please.